# ccsm changes have no effect

Tags: unity, 11.10, ccsm

After upgrading to Oneiric I want to tweak some Unity settings, but changing anything with CompizConfig Settings Manager has no effect. I tried to relogin or reboot but it didn't help.

In Natty I used only gnome (unity didn't started because of a driver issue).

Also, when I first started ccsm, Ubuntu Unity Plugin was not enabled, which seemed strange to me. I enabled it, resolving some conflicts to make sure that each setting is enabled for Unity and not the conflicting plugin.

Comment: I have a similar issue where when I boot up, my custom expo and scale plugin edge settings dont work until I make compiz restart by enabling or disabling another plugin like 'shelf', which makes it restart and then makes my settings work.  Have you tried unity --reset from a terminal

Comment: Make sure that you are actually running Unity and not Unity 2D: if your top panel has no shadow, you are running Unity 2D, which cannot be configured via ccsm.

Comment: So, how does one configure Unity 2D then?

Answer (score 1):

Also had some problems with Compiz following an upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10.

Just finished performing a clean install of 11.10 Desktop (32bit), now CompizConfig works fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing `libdconf0`. Install it and you should be fine. Click: [libdconf0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libdconf0) [image: Install libdconf0] or run:

```
sudo apt-get install libdconf0
```