# How can I adjust the transparency of the Status Bar (top panel)?

Tags: unity, panel, statusbar

The status bar (by default) at the top of your screen with the icons `OFF` to the right, `date`, `user name` and other computer options.

How can I make that bar transparent, like it is when `dash` activated (as seen in a screen below)?

[image: Transparent menu bar]

Instead of having this:

[image: No transparency on bar (yuck)]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## example panel transparency

For example 100% transparency...

[image]

A useful option if you are using transparency is the option just below - *Transparency Maximized Toggle* (called *Opaque panel for maximized windows* in Unity-Tweak-Tool)

Switching on this option will not display the top panel as transparent if the window is maximised i.e. with 100% transparency but this toggle switch-on:

[image]

Nautilus is maximised and therefore the top-bar does not remain transparent.

## 13.04

The panel transparency can be defined with [unity-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool)

[image: Install unity-tweak-tool]

[image: pic4]

## [12.04](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity)

(click to install)

The panel transparency can now be defined in *MyUnity*

[image]

Answer (score 21):

From the terminal, you can use

```
gsettings get org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ panel-opacity
```

to get the current value for panel opacity and

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ panel-opacity X
```

to set the panel opacity to `X`. `X` must be between 0 and 1.

<sub>P:S This way is preferred over any other method that uses dconf directly. And safer than using CCSM</sub>

See also:

- [Can I change the Unity Launcher transparency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33043/can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-transparency)

Answer (score 8):

### For 12.04 and 12.10 - Using CCSM

Since existing Unity configuration tools are not yet updated for 12.10, we are confined to using CCSM. Before we get going, here's some precaution:

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

If you still want to persist, install [compizconfig-settings-manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) and go to Ubuntu Unity plugin:

[image: Ubuntu unity plugin]

Navigate to Experimental tab and input any value between the range of 0.0000 to 1.0000 in the option *Panel Opacity*, where 0.0000 is complete transparent and 1.0000 is complete opaque.

[image: panel opacity]

Here's what my top panel looks like at 0.3670 opacity:

[image: top panel]

Answer (score 4):

You want to change the opacity of the Panel. Some helpful terminology definitions for Unity are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements).

The way to do this is to install CompizConfig Settings Manager from the Software Center. After it installs, launch it. Find the setting you want in Ubuntu Unity Plugin/Experimental/Panel Opacity. Slide the marker where you want it to adjust. There is no save button, just close the settings window.

Comment: This doesn't have the outcome I am looking for, that's why I posted images.

Comment: I just tested it and it works as expected. You may have a problem with settings not being applied for some reason? No sure what to do when that happens, sorry. Nice kitty, btw.

Comment: Just found this, you might want to try it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67091/ccsm-changes-have-no-effect

Comment: Thanks, :). I looked through the link, didn't help me. I should point out that I can change the opacity, but the end result doesn't look like what's in the (1st) image.

Comment: @DarkSlipstream The first image shows the Dash open. While it's open, the panel will change accordingly to that specific style. If you want it to look that way even when the Dash is not open, you may want to try finding a Unity-compatible theme that changes the look of the panel, probably to something flat.

Comment: @JE2Tom +1 for the link to the terminology definitions.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Do you have any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: There are several differences in the top picture. You can't enable them all to always be shown. The window controls, colored icons, drop shadow and edge border all change, as well as a blur effect. Compiz Settings can only change Panel transparency.

Comment: @JE2Tom Is there any way to force the panel to always look like it does when the dash is activated (top picture)?

Comment: @DarkSlipstream I think that's the key question here, to which I must admit I do not know the answer to. Whatever solution exists would probably take a fair amount of work, considering all the modifications you would have to make.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I leave most everything on default, and this has greatly reduced my frustration when using the computer. You need to find a theme that has the design elements you want, and apply it. Then cross your fingers and hope it doesn't break anything else... This might also be a good question for the chat room linked at the top of the page.

Comment: @BrianGraham What you're wanting has to do with theme, not transparency. Please edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.06 was the unity tweak tool -> Panel than adjust transparency level an uncheck Opac Panel for maximized windows...