# How do I get a pretty top bar?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I adjust the transparency of the top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-top-panel)

When opening the unity interface or when I press ALT, the top bar looks very sleek and pretty, as opposed to it's usual gradient misplacedness. Is it possible to have it look pretty all the time?

Comment: Can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-top-panel) and see if it helps? If not, try editing your question with more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, i've adjusted the opacity setting in CCSM and indeed the panel does become transparent, but it's not the same panel. Even though both are transparent, they are of different design.

Edit: The thread you pointed me to notes the same thing. It's mentioned that one can install a different theme with the design elements one wishes to have. Too bad =/

Comment: In that case you should probably just delete this question, or flag it as a duplicate of the other one. You can try applying themes, but the exact effect you want cannot currently be done. I think it would take a massive amount of work to change it.