# How can I change the opacity of the task bar?

Tags: themes, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I adjust the transparency of the top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-top-panel)

Well .. the question is as simple as the title.

But for details .. I really like the look of the task bar when I start ubuntu when I choose from users accounts .. it is simple and has a little transparency .. I want to have these effects on my task bar all the time.

How can I change the opacity and the color of the task bar ? Is it themes ?! How can I find trusted ones and how to install them ?!