# Ubuntu 12.10 transparent window title bar

Tags: unity, 12.10, window, transparency, myunity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I adjust the transparency of the top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-top-panel)

I would like to set transparency to window title bar in Ubuntu 12.10.
I used settings in gconf-editor->apps->gwd and set transparency there. This works in Ubuntu 12.04, but in 12.10 does not for me.

- Is there any possibility to change it?
- I am also wonder if there is any tweak editor like MyUnity or UnSettings which obviously doesnt work.

Comment: Window title bar is not the top panel. It is top part of the window(such as top of nautilus window, top of browser window, etc.).