# Transparent window title bar

Tags: unity, 14.04

Does anybody know how to enable the transparent window title bar in Ubuntu 14.04?

For previous versions (13.10 and 13.04) you can use [this method](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/transparent-panel-titlebar-ubuntu-unity/), but it doesn’t work any more in 14.04.

I'm not referring to the [top-panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70910/how-can-i-adjust-the-transparency-of-the-status-bar-top-panel) in Ubuntu - I'm referring to the title-bar of the window.

Comment: 14.04 is not using the metacity theme engine by default anymore, so those dconf setting won't have any effect. There's a new theme system based on gtk-css, but I don't know enough about it yet to say how to enable the effect that you want. For more info, see [Theming](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming)

Comment: 14.04 needs at least a mouse with 3 keys and 1 wheel - you could take a logitech mouse with some more keys. and about creating transparency you could follow this link - https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cOiPU-aMFsWg8weU7IDICg#q=gimp+how+to+create+transparent

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial solution, as I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work for active window.

As mentioned by [chaskes](https://askubuntu.com/users/117123/chaskes), decoration transparency now is defined by themes using CSS (property or external background image).

Tested with Ambiance theme:

- modified

  ```
  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css
  ```
- by commenting `background-image` of `UnityDecoration.top` and `UnityDecoration.top:backdrop` leaving `background-color: transparent;`

  ```
  UnityDecoration.top {
      ...
      background-color: transparent;
      ...
      /*
      background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                       from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.5)),
                                       to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.04)));
      */
      ...
  }

  UnityDecoration.top:backdrop {
      ...
      background-color: transparent;
      ...
      /*
      background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                       from (shade (#474642, 0.92)),
                                       to (@dark_bg_color));
      */
  }
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this got me to the right place to set rgba colors for the theme I was using - http://i.stack.imgur.com/HsTSP.png

Comment: @Sneetsher:  To fix the active window, you just need to make a few more changes:  
  
In the UnityDecoration.top section, comment out the 'color:' line, and add 'background-image: none;' to replace the image line you commented out.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: This has undesirable side-effects, so back up the files you modify in case you can't live with the side-effects.

Do what @Sneetsher did.

Then also comment out all `background-image` sections in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-panel.css`

Now open `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css`. Your lines 1926 to 1960 (hopefully) read as follows:

```
/* primary-toolbar */
.primary-toolbar,
.primary-toolbar .toolbar,
.primary-toolbar.toolbar,
.menubar.toolbar,
.header-bar {
    -GtkWidget-window-dragging: true;

    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.96)),
                                     to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.4)));
    border-bottom-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.1);
    border-top-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.09);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;

    color: @dark_fg_color;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.7);

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.94);
}

.primary-toolbar .toolbar:backdrop,
.primary-toolbar.toolbar:backdrop,
.menubar.toolbar .toolbar:backdrop,
.menubar.toolbar.toolbar:backdrop,
.header-bar:backdrop {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: @dark_bg_color;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-top-color: @dark_bg_color;
    border-bottom-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.9);

    color: @backdrop_dark_fg_color;
}
```

Change them to this:

```
/* primary-toolbar */
.primary-toolbar,
.primary-toolbar .toolbar,
.primary-toolbar.toolbar,
.menubar.toolbar,
.header-bar {
    -GtkWidget-window-dragging: true;

    /*background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.96)),
                                     to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.4)));
    border-bottom-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.1);
    border-top-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.09);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;*/

    /*color: @dark_fg_color;*/
    text-shadow: 0 -1px shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.7);

    /*box-shadow: inset 0 1px shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.94);*/
}

.primary-toolbar .toolbar:backdrop,
.primary-toolbar.toolbar:backdrop,
.menubar.toolbar .toolbar:backdrop,
.menubar.toolbar.toolbar:backdrop,
.header-bar:backdrop {
    background-image: none;
    /*background-color: @dark_bg_color;*/
    box-shadow: none;
    /*border-top-color: @dark_bg_color;
    border-bottom-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.9);*/

    color: @backdrop_dark_fg_color;
}
```

Now when you restart unity, active windows will also have a transparent toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and unfortunately didn't really find a good answer. I can tell you, however, that there is still a theme "GnomishGrey" buried somewhere that works the way you want (I didn't really have time to go looking where it actually is, sorry, but it's not in /usr/share/themes ...) I'm pretty sure I haven't installed it manually and I'm running Trusty Tahr.
Enable it by simply typing

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'GnomishGrey'
```

in a terminal (note the 'e' in Grey, not 'a'). I don't really use it, but from what I quickly tested, it works fine also with other transparency settings (ccsm), see picture. [image]

Another possibility would be using an emerald theme. As far as I read, it works for 14.04 (but you have to use a ppa to install it), but I don't want to try it out as there might be some issues and I quite like my setup as it is now...

Hope that maybe helps somewhat, even if it's not really an answer.

Comment: It is not buried. Ubuntu has **no theme named 'GnomishGrey'** you can type any name which is not available in system. You can try this **gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'abcxyz'**