# Transparent Window Title Bars 14.04LTS

Tags: customization, dconf, transparency, titlebar

I can't figure out how to get transparent window title bars in 14.04

Have tried dconfig editor which has no effect (worked on previous versions)

Any suggestions or step-by-steps massively appreciated.

D

Comment: By dconfig do you mean setting the `metacity_theme_active_opacity` and `metacity_theme_opacity` values?

Comment: Yes, I change them to a more transparent setting and nothing changes?  Annoying.

Comment: Try this one from  https://askubuntu.com/a/722235/26246