# Make any application window title bar transparent in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, titlebar, transparency, css

How can I make application window bars transparent in Ubuntu 18.04? I've searched online but haven't found anything for this version.

Comment: No. This is a solution for Xubuntu, NOT for ubuntu.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442269/transparent-window-title-bar) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for this link. The ubuntu version is doubtful but i will give a try. Will get back.